# Redux Form - How to validate async blur field arrays?

Tags: validation, redux-form

I have a FieldArray like this:

```
renderLanguages = fields => (
    <div>
      {fields.map(fieldName => <Field name={fieldName + '.iso'} component="input" type="text" />
    </div>
)
```

`<FieldArray name="languages" component={renderLanguages} />`

And i like to validate it in a async way:

```
const asyncValidate = values => {
  console.log(values);
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'languagesForm',
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ['languages']
})(LanguagesForm)
```

My asyncValidate never gets called. I wonder if i have to specify the asyncBlur fields in an other way. Or if redux-form does not provide the async validation of field arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To get `Redux-form` FormArray working with the [asyncValidate](https://redux-form.com/7.4.0/examples/asyncchangevalidation/), it requires to pass the field as `languages[].<nameOfTheFieldOfChildComponet>` but not `languages` only. 
I think its good design too as generally, we don't validate asynchronously on change of any parameter but a specific parameter.

Here is the working example:- https://codesandbox.io/s/mq8zz58mrj

```
const asyncValidate = values => {
  console.log(values);
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'languagesForm',
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ['languages[].name']
})(LanguagesForm)
```